# How to debug a project file in MSBuild 12.0 / VS2013?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

[Tracing a project was easy in MSBuild 4.0 / VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx), all you had to do was set registry key which enabled an msbuild /debug command line option.  The debugger would launch and break at the start of the project file.

MSBuild 12 introduces a new environment variable for this. At the command prompt, set MSBUILDDEBUGONSTART=1 and then run MSBuild (no command line switch).  This launches the debugger, but **does no break**.  The project just runs to completion with VS open.

Am I missing a setting?  Or has this (undocumented) feature been removed?  I was able to at least get the debugger to halt by hard coding in a debug break, but this does not help me trace the *project* file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         InitialTargets="Init">

  <UsingTask TaskName="LaunchDebugger"
             TaskFactory="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeTaskFactory"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup />
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          System.Console.WriteLine("Launching debugger...");
          System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <UsingTask TaskName="DebugBreak"
             TaskFactory="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeTaskFactory"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup />
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="Init">
    <LaunchDebugger />
    <DebugBreak />
  </Target>

...
```

Comment: Then same person who told us all about the feature originally?  Either Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi or Brian Kretzler.

Comment: You should rename your question to use the well-known and correct term *debugging* instead of *tracing* so that if an answer comes up it is searchable

Comment: @stijn - no, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried that, it opens and showme the disassembly, but does not allowme to see the msbuild code or setup any breakpoints

Comment: @ImaDirtyTroll - Have you tried adding the registry key in my answer?

Answer (score 5):

Add the `DebuggerEnabled` registry value (with data `true`) to the following key(s) (the key in the blog post is out of date).

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\12.0` (64-bit systems)
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\12.0` (32-bit systems, or
if somehow running MSBuild 64-bit)

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27450702/704808
- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1029251/cannot-debug-msbuild-project-script-file#commentContainer

Comment: Works for MSBuild 12.0, doesn't work for me for 14.0. Any new knowledge about that?