# How to debug a project file in MSBuild 14.0 / VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

[How to debug a project file in MSBuild 12.0 / VS2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26079346/704808) has an answer, but apparently that method is not supported in Visual Studio 2015/MSBuild 14. Does anyone know a way to perform MSBuild debugging in Visual Studio 2015/MSBuild 14? Bonus points for scoop about Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MSBuild debugger was never officially supported and was [cut from MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/144) in favor of cross-platform support in the VS 2015/MSBuild 14 timeframe.

There are many ways to debug the behavior of a build. The combination of a `Verbosity=Diagnostic` build log and the preprocessed project (`msbuild /pp:preprocessed.xml path\to\the.csproj` creates a file containing all of the build logic for a given project) is extremely powerful. You may also be interested in the UI that the [MSBuildStructuredLog](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog) provides, which helps pare down the massive output produced by a diagnostic log.

Comment: Agreed-- debugger-less debugging is doubtlessly doable. And thanks for the tip on [MSBuildStructuredLog](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog). I have occasionally used [MSBuildExplorer](https://github.com/bryanar/MSBuildExplorer) to aid static analysis of MSBuild scripts, but this looks like it may really speed (post-execution) debugging. This feature particularly excites me: _"Displays double-writes (when files from different sources are written to the same destination during a build, thus causing non-determinism)."_

Answer (score 3):

It really works well in old VS version:

[image]

But if I use the VS2015, I got the same issue as yours, it could recognize the /debug command line.

I report this issue to the product team here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/3120913/how-to-debug-a-project-file-in-msbuild-14-0-vs2015

You could check the latest update from it, of course, please also vote and add your comment there:)